# SketchUp WebDialog does not execute JS and action_callback

Tags: javascript, ruby, sketchup

I have the following index.html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Hello World</title>
  <script>
    function close() {
      window.location.href = 'skp:closeDialog@someString';
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id='data'>Text will go here...</p>
  <button onclick="close()">Done</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And I have the following ruby script:

```
dlg = UI::WebDialog.new( "Hello World", "", false, 500, 300, 433, 234, false )

dlg.set_file( File.dirname(__FILE__) + 'index.html' )
dlg.add_action_callback( "closeDialog" ) {|dialog, params|
    data = dlg.get_element_value( "data" )
    puts data
    dlg.close
}
dlg.show {
    dlg.execute_script( "document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = 'Hello World!'" )
}
```

For some reason neither the script that should change the value of the `<p>` element nor the callback action does not work. The strange thing is, that if I change the JS to

```
dlg.execute_script( "alert('Hello World!')" )
```

then the alert message is shown upon start.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the block in `.show` - the HTML might not be ready yet. Have a look at this article: https://github.com/thomthom/sketchup-webdialogs-the-lost-manual/wiki/window.onload

Given this script:

```
module TT_Test
  @d = nil
  @d = UI::WebDialog.new('On Load Test')
  @d.add_action_callback('onload') { |dialog, params|
    puts '>> window.onload'
  }
  @d.set_html('Onload Test')
  def self.onload
    @d.show {
      puts '>> ruby block'
    }
  end
end
```

Windows:

```
load 'test/webdialog.rb'
true
TT_Test.onload
true
>> ruby block
>> window.onload
```

OSX:

```
> load 'test/webdialog.rb'
true
>> window.onload
> TT_Test.onload
true
```

Observe that the block in `show` isn't reliable in terms of the `onLoad` event.

What I always do is use jQuery's `ready` event and send a callback to Ruby - that way I know the dialog's content is ready. And only in that callback will I perform setup etc.

As for `dlg.get_element_value( "data" )` - the `data` element in your code is a `<p>`: `<p id='data'>Text will go here...</p>`. `get_element_value` is working only for form elements.

Note that in your `add_action_callback` you have the `params` argument - that will contain the data after `@` in `skp:closeDialog@someString`.